# How to create a new file type on Windoes 10 running a specific cmd command

Tags: windows, file-extension

I just for fun coded a brainfuck compiler in python and now would like to add a new file extension like .brainfuck, which will run the command `py C:\Program Files (x86)\Brainfuck\brainfuck.py [name of the doubleclicked file]`.

Is there a way, I can do this?
I know I can create new types via the regedit, but don't know how I can't run specific things on doubleclick.
I know I can change the standard app via file associations, but I cannot tell it to run a cmd command. Also when I'm trying to set a standard, it says that there is no app installed for it.

Comment: You're looking for "file associations" menu in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Follow [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-intro), this stuff has not changed much since 1995. This is the information you must write to the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.brainfuck
  ""=brainfuckfile

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\brainfuckfile\shell\open\command
  ""="c:\path\to\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Brainfuck\brainfuck.py" "%1"
```

(Change HKEY_CURRENT_USER to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE if you want to register for all users)